# Can't install npm packages on Raspberry Pi 2Gb - installation freezing on 'reify:@types/node: timing reifyNode:node_modules/jquery' message

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, electron

I'm trying to install npm packages on a Raspberry Pi 2Gb and when i run the command "sudo npm i" it is getting freeze on message: "reify:@types/node: timing reifyNode:node_modules/jquery completed in 1959m". And another thing important to say is if i cancel the instalation with Control+C and check the files in the directory, appears the folder node_modules but doesnt appear the file "package-lock.json"

**My dependices are:**

```
"dependencies": {
   "datatables.net": "^1.13.1",
   "electron": "^22.1.0",
   "mysql": "^2.18.1",
   "python-shell": "^3.0.1"
}
```

NodeJS Version: v19.9.0
NPM Version: 9.6.3

Ps.: The project is made with Electron (i'm not sure if it's very important)

I've already tried re-install nodeJs and Npm but the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue, the problem seems to be hardware rather than software as newer versions of npm cannot install packages (I was using 18.17.0)

You can reinstall the older versions of node and npm using
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm git make g++ gcc`

You can try installing unofficial builds by working out what arm verison you are running using `uname -m` to see if you are running an ARM version supported by the unofficial binaries. But I tried this and had to end up re-installing the node version that comes by default.